# Django Model: creating a new object on save for FK

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django Model I have the following FK on a class called Batch.

```
class Batch(models.Model):
    sender_name = models.ForeignKey(Originator,
                                        related_name='batch')
```

Now, this means a user always has to first create a Originator before saving. I would like however, if Originator does not exist then created a new one and add it to the batch. I was thinking of doing this on save() of batch. but is there a better way?

Comment: is the creation of Batch through a form ?

Comment: it could be, but also via tasypie api. Any get_or_create() shortcuts?

Comment: You could do it in the save method, but I would put the logic before the models' save method - when you receive the context data from tastypie, so that way you dont mix up the logic - Avoid creating an object of a different class, in another classes' save method

Comment: So your saying do this in the view or in tastypies case hydrate? i.e.  bundle.data['contact'] = Originator.objects.get_or_create()

Comment: Yes.. That way the logic is clean, and all you have to do save() .

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense now. Could you answer that so I can accept as that's perfect it's just want I needed to know .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the `FK` object in the `view` method, or in case of tastypie, hydrate.

By not putting the FK object creation logic in the `save` method of the model, you dont mix up the logic. In other words, Avoid creating an object of a one class, in another classes' `save` method.

That way the logic is clean, and all you have to do is `bundle.data['contact'] = Originator.objects.get_or_create()` instead of overriding the `save`